# Synthesize more than 1500 characters using AWS Polly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

My idea was to use `AWS Polly` to read aloud some news from an `RSS` feed. As per [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/pricing/) I understand that Polly is very flexible in terms of characters to be converted as one of the examples is `"Adventures of Huckelberry Finn" by Mark Twain ~600k characters` 
The problem is that when I try to convert my articles to speech I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (TextLengthExceededException) when calling the SynthesizeSpeech operation: Maximum text length has been exceeded
```

The text I was trying to convert was about 5000 characters.

Is there any way (with or without the API) to convert long strings of text with Polly without having to cut them into million different pieces?

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The size of the input text can be up to 1500 billed characters (3000 total characters). SSML tags are not counted as billed characters.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/limits.html

The [pricing examples](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/pricing/) seem to be intended to give a sense of the relatively low cost of voicing a large work, but the work would actually need to be divided into groups of sentences and submitted to the API, which is the only interface -- the SDKs and CLI call the same [`SynthesizeSpeech`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_SynthesizeSpeech.html) API.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you would submit multiple groups (and end up with a single contiguous audio stream)?  If I submit multiple groups and get multiple byte arrays back, I don't think they can simply be combined.

Comment: @Howiecamp, I didn't intend to imply that they could necessarily be simply concatenated.  Ideally you'd use a library for manipulating audio files in your format of choice so that the metadata would be correct.  With mp3, at least, it might work better than you anticipate.

Comment: Gotcha thank you. Any guess on why the character limit is so darn low?

Comment: I can only speculate, but I assume it's because it's (evidently) designed for/targeted towards talking apps and interactive voice response (IVR) systems (as evidenced by support for the μ-law codec) where a quick response is generally needed.  Beyond some limit, a suitably fast turnaround would be impossible.

Comment: I just found that you can literally just append multiple MP3 files together (read first, read second, etc and write all to a new file) and the audio is completely preserved. Would be advisable to do some tag cleanup but the audio certainly works.

Comment: In April 2018 AWS doubled the maximum numbers: "The size of the input text can be up to 3000 billed characters (6000 total characters). SSML tags are not counted as billed characters."

Answer (score 2):

How to create long audio files is described in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/longer-cli.html

An aws-CLI call might look like this:

```
aws polly start-speech-synthesis-task \
--region eu-central-1 \
--endpoint-url "https://polly.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/" \
--output-format mp3 \
--output-s3-bucket-name your-bucket-name \
--output-s3-key-prefix optional/prefix/path/file \
--voice-id Hans \
--text-type ssml \
--text file://output.xml \
--speech-mark-types='["sentence", "word", "ssml"]' \
```

As you can see you will need an S3-bucket for (temporay) storage.

Comment: This allows you to process texts with "up to 100,000 billable characters (or 200,000 total characters)" with the same functionality but the request may take longer because the processing is asynchronous. The processing is done "as soon as the system resources are available" [ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/asynchronous.html ]

Answer (score 1):

I have no special tip without breaking a text in pieces, but i wrote an article with the way to do it in NodeJS. If you don't have any other alternative, feel free to review and comment it !

[How to handle more than 1500 characters with AWS Polly text-to-speech](https://medium.com/@Feawel/handler-for-more-than-1500-characters-with-aws-polly-api-in-node-js-559e74cfb185#.61wgropn2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have already found an answer to this or moved on by now.
But I want to help anyone in the future with this problem.

I had the same issue using AWS Polly not letting me send more than 1500 chars at a time. So I wrote some javascript to help break the text into 230 word chunks then send to the API one after another then stitch all the mp3 files together before I buffered it and played it.

Here is my Github for it:
https://github.com/Aaronbest94/Polly-Character-Limitations

Its not the most elegant Javascript be it does work and I hope it will help anyone reading this in the future.