# Amazon Polly Implementation Using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-polly

I am trying to integrate the Amazon Polly web service into one of my projects using Amazon's PHP SDK. But when I used the PollyClient SDK, there is only one method implemented in the client `createSynthesizeSpeechPreSignedUrl()` and it returns a url, not the audio clip. When I try and paste the url in the browser window I get the following error: `"message": "The security token included in the request is invalid."`

Please see my code snippet:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
require_once 'app/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Polly\PollyClient;

class TestPolly extends Base {
    public function newPolly () {
        $connection = [
            'region'      => 'us-west-2',
            'version'     => 'latest',
            'debug'       => true,
            'scheme'      => 'http',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => 'XXXXX',
                'secret' => 'XXXXXX',
            ],
        ];
        $client     = new PollyClient($connection);
        $polly_args = [
            'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
            'Text'         => 'My Input text',
            'TextType'     => 'text',
            'VoiceId'      => 'Brain',
        ];
        $result     = $client->synthesizeSpeech($polly_args);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        exit;
    }
}
```

The PHP error I am getting is:

```
Fatal error Uncaught exception 'Aws\Polly\Exception\PollyException' with message 'Error executing &quot;SynthesizeSpeech on http://polly.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/speech

 AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to polly.us-west-2.amazonaws.com port 80: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'

exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException' with message 'cURL error 7: Failed to connect to polly.us-west-2.amazonaws.com port 80: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in D:\xampp\htdocs\sim_aws\aws\GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory.php:186
Stack trace:
```

The interesting part is, I was able to generate the audio clip using Node.js SDK, so I'm quite sure that the access key and secret key is working fine.

It would be great if anyone can point out how the PHP SDK can be used with sample code or useful links.

Answer (score 11):

Here is some sample code to download the TTS as an .mp3 file in the browser, the crucial part is `$result->get('AudioStream')->getContents()`, this is what gets the actual .mp3 data.

```php
require_once 'app/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
$awsAccessKeyId = 'XXXXXXX';
$awsSecretKey   = 'XXXXXXX';
$credentials    = new \Aws\Credentials\Credentials($awsAccessKeyId, $awsSecretKey);
$client         = new \Aws\Polly\PollyClient([
    'version'     => '2016-06-10',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region'      => 'us-east-1',
]);
$result         = $client->synthesizeSpeech([
    'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
    'Text'         => "My input text",
    'TextType'     => 'text',
    'VoiceId'      => 'Joanna',
]);
$resultData     = $result->get('AudioStream')->getContents();

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3');
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($resultData));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pollyTTS.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

echo $resultData;
```

As for links, here are a few:

- Polly docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-polly-2016-06-10.html
- Polly pricing: https://aws.amazon.com/polly/pricing/
- Getting started with AWS PHP SDK: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/

Comment: How to increase characters length when using TextType as SSML ? because its only allow me about 1450-1500 characters per PHP mp3 file convert... @David

Comment: I don't know how to do that @JigneshVagh, but you could have a look through this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41317999/3088508) for some ideas. You are only allowed 1500 _billed_ characters for each api call. [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/limits.html)

Comment: i implemented some time ago a service with ivona, now acquired by amazon. With your example i converted my code to polly in no-time. Lifesaver!

Comment: Work like a charm !

Comment: ```$result         = $client->synthesizeSpeech([
    'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
    'Text'         => "D. A",
    'TextType'     => 'text',
    'LanguageCode' => 'arb'
]);  ``` LanguageCode not working, any idea?

Comment: @coder618 It might be because you're not passing `VoiceId` as well, but your best bet would be to ask a new question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Nope, you are right @Ethan, have to pass a valid voice id if use LanguageCode!